# SelectPicker: How to get json value and display inside dropdownlist as checked option?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-selectpicker

How to get values from JSON and display these values as checked options inside selectpicker using ajax success response? I'm try to use selectpicker **$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['values'])** val method to get values and display as checked option.

To describe more clear, below are two tables: **color_tbl** table and **cars_tbl** table:

**color_tbl**

```
colorID | color    | 
--------------------
01      | White    |
02      | Gray     |
03      | Black    |
04      | Red      |
--------------------
```

**cars_tbl**

```
carID | car    | Color (Foreing Key) and select multiple
---------------------------------------------------------
01    | Ford   | 01, 02, 03
02    | GM     | 02, 03, 04
03    | BMW    | 01, 03, 04
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Below are the selectpicker method:

```
$ ('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['values']);
```

And below are the jquery function that execute a bootstrap modal, and inside this function, ajax receive data from php script and pass values in JSON format:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_single.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {

                $('#userModal').modal('show');
                $('#car').val(data.car);
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [data.color]);

            }
        })
    });
```

As the code above, when modal is open, the input **#car** receive correct data but selectpicker dropdownlist **#color** dont receive data.

I tried to put *[data.color]* inside selectpicker val method but no success. I'm try to find a correct way to get json object value to put inside this method and display checked options related to color column from *cars_tbl* table.

how could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to solve my doubt. To turn a comma delimited string in to an array, i used 'split()' into selectpicker val method as below:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', data.color.split(','));
```

and it works now.